# update array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am able to save new list and get all data btw How can i update below array. Will i have to update each object with forEach replace it with new one?

Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 
var TypeOfAccountSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
});
 
module.exports = mongoose.model('typeofaccount', TypeOfAccountSchema);
```

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5efc26348150a306b017090e",
        "name": "Saving Account",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5efc26348150a306b017090f",
        "name": "Current Account",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5efc26678150a306b0170912",
        "name": "Saving1 Account",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: do you want to update whole array by name or update only one array by it's id?

Comment: user can update name in array by id but cant update update id, so in PUT request i am going to have whole updated array, User will not send me one one object

Answer (score 0):

You can use following logic, instead of using a forEach.

```
let p = [];
for (let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
    let { _id, ...rest } = req.body[i];
    let r = Typeofaccount.update({_id}, {$set: {...rest}})
    p.push(r);
}
Promise.all(p)
.then(data => {
    res.json({status: 200, message: "Updated"});
})
.catch(err => {
    return res.status(500).json({message : err.message})
})
```

Comment: req.body.accounts this will be undefined i am passing an array for update and want to update by ID

Comment: I have assumed req.body.accounts has the array that you want to update. Basically you can replace it with which field in req.body has your array.

Comment: i want to update by id what i will have to put in query condition ?

Comment: Assuming you are sending Account identifier as _id in req.body then it would be as follow _id: ObjectId(req.body._id)

Comment: my request doesnt have extra key than above array,  I think i will have to loop array then update each name by _id, (main post array is the only original response)

Comment: Ok. Got it. Wait I'll share a solution for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217009/discussion-between-shreeram-k-and-indraraj26).